# Default Input from variable

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to call a table valued function with some variable inputs.  However, I'd like to use the function's `default` value if the calling script doesn't set the input value.

So, assume I have the function (yes, this is a silly function)

```
create function dbo.testing(@countTo int=10)
returns @output table(num int)
as
 begin
    declare @i int
    set @i=0
    while @i < @countTo
     begin
        set @i=@i+1

        insert into @output(num)
        values(@i)
     end

    return
 end
```

Then, I could setup a variable for the input:

```
declare @stop int
set @stop=15

select * from dbo.testing(@stop)
```

However, if `@stop` is left as `null`, I'd like to use the `default` value, but it will just use `null` (which returns nothing...).  Essentially, I want the following to work:

```
select * from dbo.testing(isnull(@stop,default))
```

But it just returns the error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'default'.

Is there anyway to do this without modifying the function?

Answer (score 2):

After researching this a bit my conclusion (I could be wrong though) is that you can't do this without either modifying the function as described below or include a conditional null check when you call the function as:

```
if @stop is null
select * from dbo.testing(default)
else
select * from dbo.testing(@stop)
```

This might not be practical though. The alternative is to modify your function to include a null check and default value:

```
create function dbo.testing(@countTo int)
returns @output table(num int)
as
 begin
    if @countTo is null set @countto = 10
    declare @i int
    set @i=0
    while @i < @countTo
     begin
        set @i=@i+1

        insert into @output(num)
        values(@i)
     end

    return
 end
```

And call it like `select * from dbo.testing(isnull(@stop,null))`